# R-type blockquotes in BBEdit

Tags: bbedit, blockquote

How can I quickly add R-type quotes (`#`) to multiple lines in BBEdit, and how can I quickly remove them again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the lines you want and from the menu select Text->Prefix/Suffix Lines... and enter "# " in the prefix section. To remove them do the same thing but select "remove".

Answer (score 1):

If your document's language is set to R, you can select the lines you want to comment, and do Edit->Un/Comment. BBEdit knows how to comment it correctly if you have the right language selected.